# Process not taking arguments

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am trying to run ffmpeg.exe as a process and give it some arguments. The process actually runs I can see the ffmpeg window opens but then nothing happens. I also tried using `@ffmpeg` in the args but no luck. So I guess the arguments are not passing to it. I have manually run the ffmpeg.exe from cmd and used those args and it worked perfectly. Here is the code,

```
public void ConvertVideo()
{
    var dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\FFMpeg";
    var ffmpeg = dir + "\\ffmpeg.exe";
    var args = "ffmpeg -i 20180906194502.mp4 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 20  output.mp4";

    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.Start();
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(args);
    process.StandardInput.Flush();
    process.StandardInput.Close();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

So bottom line is, if I run this code I just see this window and then nothing happens. [image: ffmpeg window]

Comment: I would be very surprised if you really have to pass `ffmpeg` as first argument (before `-i`)

Comment: ok i have removed `ffmpeg` from the args. now the args looks like `var args = "-i 20180906194502.mp4 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 20 output.mp4";` and still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing 'args' variable:
   process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

Answer (score 2):

There is "Arguments" property available inside StartInfo.
Can you try in the following way..

```
Process p= new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg ;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Yes it worked thanks but I have already accepted another answer :)